# Future functions in a loop not working

Tags: dart

I want to execute same future function with different values. The order is not important. But I want to execute some functions after the above future function. My idea is

```
addrMapList.forEach((addrMap){ //length is 3
    exeQuery(sql).then((result){
      print(result);
    });
});
print('All finished');
// other actions

Future exeQuery(String sql){
    var c=new Completer();
    Random rnd=new Random();
    c.complete(rnd.nextInt(100));
    return c.future;
}

But the result is

All finished
72
90
74


But I need a result like

72
90
74
All finished
```

How can this implement in dart.. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/efeaad76a887a014818f) is modified version of your sample to work as you expected it to.

First of all, you should understand how asynchronous code works, and why it was not in your case:

When you write constructions like `<some future>.then( (){...} );` you are not immediately running code defined inside `.then( )`. You just defining a callback, to be called later. So, in your code, you're defined 3 callbacks, and then, immediately, printed "All finished", at the time when no of your futures even started to work. At this moment they are just sitting in dart's event loop and waiting for a chance to be executed. And they will get that chance only when you finish execution of current code, and not a moment earlier, because Isolate is run as a single thread.

I used `Future.wait()` to wait for multiple futures because you said order is not important. This is more efficient then waiting Futures one by one. But if order is important, you have to use `Future.forEach()`, it will not start execution of second Future until first one is completed.

One more thing in your code is that your function returning a Future is actually synchronous, because it always returns already completed Future. This is also changed in dartpad sample above to better visualize how asynchronous code works.

Comment: can you give a sample code which use Future.forEach()

Comment: It's the same, just replace `wait` with `forEach`. But it will not return you list of results, you have to store them somewhere by yourself if you need them. You will only know when all futures are completed.

Comment: I need to save multiple address for a person object in json format. Each person contain a array of address id's. When I try with my idea all this are saved in database.. but the person object is going to database before getting the address id. So I need to save all address objects first..then collect the ids..with this ids save the person object. So with the great help from your side.. I will try my best..

Answer (score 0):

forEach can't be used this way. Use `await for` instead (the enclosing function needs to be `async`)

```
Future someFunc() async {
  await for (var addrMap in addrMapList) {
    var result = await exeQuery(sql);
    print(result);
  } 
  // other action 
}
```